# Let $f$ be a differentiable function such that $f(0)=0$. The function $f$ is odd if and only if its derivative, $f'$, is even.

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation

I need to show both directions of this biconditional statement.

Let $f$ be a differentiable function such that $f(0)=0$. The function $f$ is odd if and only if its derivative, $f'$, is even.

Answer (score 4):

Assume $f$ is odd. Then 
$$\begin{align} f'(-x)&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(-x+h)-f(-x)}{h}\\&=-\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x-h)-f(x)}{h}\\&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x-h)-f(x)}{-h}\\&=f'(x)\end{align}$$

---

Assume $f'$ is even.
Then the derivative of $g(x)= f(x)+f(-x)$ is $g'(x)=f'(x)-f'(-x)=0$, hence $g$ is constant. From $g(0)=0$ we conclude $f(x)+f(-x)=0$ for all $x$.